# Rails RSpec - error when testing have_link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, specifications, link-to

I want to test my home page. Links to itself should not be.
Why is not true?

spec/features/main_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe "main pages", :type => :features do

  subject { page }
  ...
  context "root page" do

    it "should have the link 'Home'" do
      visit root_path
      expect(page).to have_link('Home', href: '#')
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

app/views/main_pages/home.html.erb

```
...
<%=link_to("Home", "#") %>
...
```

=>

```
main pages root page should have the link 'Home'
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_link('Home', href: '#')
       expected #has_link?("Home", {:href=>"#"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/features/main_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

UPDATE:
Anyone can help?

Comment: What's in your routes.rb?

Comment: @AndreyTurkin root  'main_pages#home'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 context "root page" do
    before { visit root_path }
    it "should have the link 'Home'" do      
      expect(page).to have_link('Home', href: '#')
    end
  end
```

Comment: No, it does not work. I think the problem is not in the call page. The problem in the link "#". `expect(page).to have_link('About', href: about_path(locale: I18n.locale))` it work.